# is there any working twitter integration for android and ios

Tags: titanium-mobile

I have tried so many codes for posting tweet but i didn't find any working twitter implementation.

I have tried **social.js - social_plus.js - alloy/social - birdhouse.js** etc.

My app crashed at below line

```
correctTimestampFromSrc: function(parameterName) {
parameterName = parameterName || "oauth_timestamp";
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
```

My titanium mobile SDK 3.2.3 GA, my test platfom is iOS 7.1 simulator.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but I'm using this one of my apps.

Basically it's a fail-gracefully concept where if the user:

- has the Twitter app installed, it will open the native integration for iOS (haven't tested Android)
- otherwise, it will open up a browser and use the twitter intent url to post (making the user sign in but still keeping the populated Twitter message.

`

```
//check to see if the user can open a test url schema
if(Ti.Platform.canOpenURL('twitter://post?message=test'))
{
    //if the user can, then encode the message and open the native integration
    var twitterShareText = encodeURIComponent('Your Twitter message here'); 
    Ti.Platform.openURL('twitter://post?message=" + twitterShareText);

}else
{
    //create a url for Twitter share (then open twitterShareURL in browser)
    `var twitterShareURL = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?';
        twitterShareURL += 'text=' + encodeURIComponent('Your Twitter message here');
        twitterShareURL += 'url=' + encodeURI('http://theurlthatyouwanttoshare.com'); //(optional)
}
```